# Практические вопросы по создания консольного приложения на Python

Tags: python, ui, vmware

Я должен написать консольное ПО для копирования виртуальных машин VMware. Я долгое время работал с их софтом и знаю об копировании много. Но для этого я должен сделать программу на Python, с которым я не работал много.
Что я подразумеваю под "Консольным приложением". Программа должна запускаться в консоли из под Windows или Linux, с установленным Python. Т.е пользователь просто должен вводить в консоль адреса серверов назначения и имя ВМ, все пути и тд я укажу далее.

1. Как реализовать такой интерфейс взаимодействия пользователя и ПО и как он называется?

на данный момент мое ПО представляет это:

```
from ast import In
import paramiko

inHost = input("Enter the host address from where to copy the VM: ")
outHost = input("Enter the host address where to copy the VM: ")

inUsername = input("Enter the username for the server where the VM will be copied from: ")
outUsername = input("Enter the username for the server where the VM will be copied to: ")

inPassword = input("Enter the password for the user from whose server the copy will be made: ")
outPassw0rd = input("Enter the password for the user to whose server the copy will be made: ")

InSSHPort = input("Enter the SSH port( If the port is standard, do not enter anything) : ")
OutSSHPort = input("Enter the SSH port( If the port is standard, do not enter anything) : ")

InSSHPort = 22
OutSSHPort = 22
```

это обычные поля ввода данных. А как сделать в самом начале выбор языка, по типу "введите (1), если хотите начать на русском. Enter (2) if you want to continue in English". В самом начале ставить везде условный оператор if ? или есть другой способ?

Comment: можно сделать вызов консольки с параметрами.

Comment: а можно поточнее рассказать об этом, по типу Python для самых маленьких :)

Comment: с примерами https://jenyay.net/Programming/Argparse

Comment: "интерфейс взаимодействия пользователя и ПО и как он называется?"  ну вашему коду я бы назвал интерактивным интерфейсом, прога задает вопрос пользователь отвечает. Можно сделать типа сценария пишишь текстовой файл(мини ЯП) и скармливаешь своей проге. Если мне паметь не изменяет VMware может работать из командной строки тут даже батник можно замутить.